# Dell Poweredge 6950 CPU Upgrade

Tags: dell, central-processing-unit

Does anyone know if it's possible to upgrade the cpus in this server to Opteron 8354.
In this German version looks like it's an option. 
http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=at&l=de&s=dhs&cs=atdhs1&sku=374-11684

We replaced the CPU's and the server does not start but no message are showing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bios was upgraded

and looks ok now

here is the benchmark

http://browse.geekbench.ca/geekbench2/view/302014